# MockingKernel Named Multi-Bindings as constructor argument

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-mockingkernel

So let's say I have an interface with two implementations

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    string Hit(string target);
}

public class Sword : IWeapon 
{
    public string Hit(string target) 
    {
        return "Slice " + target + " in half";
    }
}

public class Dagger : IWeapon 
{
    public string Hit(string target) 
    {
        return "Stab " + target + " to death";
    }
}
```

I have an object that accepts a `Sword` and a `Dagger`. I use `Named` multi bindings as described in the [docs](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection).

```
public class Samurai: ISamurai
{
    private readonly IWeapon sword;
    private readonly IWeapon dagger;

    public Samurai(
        [Named(nameof(Sword))] IWeapon sword,
        [Named(nameof(Dagger))] IWeapon dagger)
    {
        this.sword = sword;
        this.dagger = dagger;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I use it with normal binding in run-time case:

```
DependencyInjector.Kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().Named(nameof(Sword));
DependencyInjector.Kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Dagger>().Named(nameof(Dagger));
```

This doesn't work when I use mocking kernel:

```
Mock<IWeapon> mockSword = new Mock<IWeapon>();
Mock<IWeapon> mockDagger = new Mock<IWeapon>();

MockingKernel.Rebind<IWeapon>().ToConstant(mockSword.Object).Named(nameof(Sword));
MockingKernel.Rebind<IWeapon>().ToConstant(mockDagger.Object).Named(nameof(Dagger));

MockingKernel.Get<Samurai>();
```

I get the following type of error:

```
Message: OneTimeSetUp: Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating 
IWeapon
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IWeapon into parameter             
sword of constructor of type ISamurai
  1) Request for ISamurai
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with `Rebind<IWeapon>()` method is that it removes all the bindings based on `IWeapon` even if you later specify `Named` syntax. This means that the second rebind call eliminates the first one. So try this instead:

```
MockingKernel.Rebind<IWeapon>().ToConstant(mockSword.Object).Named(nameof(Sword));
MockingKernel.Bind<IWeapon>().ToConstant(mockDagger.Object).Named(nameof(Dagger));
```

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks